# virtual attribute in a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

User model has **all_scores** attribute and i created the method below

models/user.rb

```
def score
  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(self.all_scores)["local"]
end
```

What i'm trying to do this using this virtual attribute score to filter users. For example:
I need the users whose score is over 50.  The problem is i can't use virtual attribute as a regular attribute in a query.

```
User.where("score > 50") # i can't do this.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the "easiest" solution would probably be `User.all.select{|user| user.score > 50}`.  Obviously that's very inefficient, pulling every User record out of the database.

If you want to do a query involving the score, why don't you add a `score` column to the users table?  You could update it whenever `all_scores` is changed.

```
class User < AR::Base
  before_save :set_score, :if => :all_scores_changed?

  protected
  def set_score
    self.score = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(self.all_scores)["local"] rescue nil
  end
end
```

This will also avoid constantly deserializing JSON data whenever you access `user#score`.