# create active record query for virtual attribute in Rails 5 or 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a virtual attribute such as `full_name`, composed of `first_name` + " " + `last_name`, and I want to find users with `User.where(full_name: "John Whoosiwhatsit")`, how can I do this?

This was apparently not possible back in [Rails 3 (or whatever was current 8 years ago)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6926125/241142), but it seems like it may have been made possible since then.

And yes, I know that in the example given there are problems when you have "Anne Marie Van Der Moss", but the point of the question is about how to do this type of thing, not whether the particular example is a good idea or easy to implement well.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Imagine having to load all records in memory and then later filter by that virtual attribute. If we would want to avoid that, I think Rails would need some sort of macro to declare virtual attributes to be used in queries and then ActiveRecord or Arel would convert them to a proper query knowing beforehand that the given attribute is configured as a virtual one composed of x fields, and then it would translate it to `AND`s in the query. But I am not aware of such feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
User.select("users.*", "CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS full_name")
    .where(full_name: "John Whoosiwhatsit")
```

This will work on MySQL, Postgres and SQLite (and probally more). ActiveRecord will map any aliased columns in the resulting rows from the query as attributes in the model.

Some dbs (like Oracle) don't let you use aliases in the WHERE clause so you would have to repeat the concatenation:

```
# Use an Enterprise DB they said. It will be fun they said.
User.select("users.*", "CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS full_name")
    .where("CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) = 'John Whoosiwhatsit'")
```

This has probally worked in almost every version since Rails AFAIK has always allowed you to revert to raw SQL if needed.

Comment: This same concept is really useful for selecting aggregates or columns from joined tables as well.